# How to find the overlap between first n string that match last n string in others python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, string, match, prefix

Assume I have two strings:

```
a = 'stackoverflow'
b =  'mathisgoodstackover'
```

I try to find the largest overlap part from the beginning of `a` that match the ending of `b`.

```
c= 'stackover'
d = 'stackoverf'
```

`c` is the optimal solution. `d` is not, since the `b` does not end with `stackoverf`.

I try to use brute-force, but not sure how to write the loop. any efficient algorithm?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the built-in function `max` with a list comprehension:

```
max([a[:i] for i in range(1,len(a) + 1) if b.endswith(a[:i])], key=len)
```

output:

```
'stackover'
```

also for special cases:

```
a = 'ssss'
b =  'mathisgoodssssss'
max([a[:i] for i in range(1,len(a) + 1) if a[:i] == b[-i:]], key=len)
```

outut:

```
'ssss'
```

or as suggested by @ShadowRanger you could start with `i` large as possible and then shrinking using [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) built-in function with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)

```
next((a[:i] for i in range(len(a), 0,-1) if b.endswith(a[:i])), '')
```

Comment: Save a little slicing work with `b.endswith(a[:i])`. You could also work backwards, with `i` starting as large as possible and shrinking, allowing you to use `next` with a genexpr instead of `max`+`key=len` (allowing you to short-circuit on the first hit, since all other hits would necessarily be smaller).